# Adding State abbreviations to map generated using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to add state abbreviations to a US map generated using ggplot2 and having some difficulties with it. I believe the "fill = " option is causing it, but I am not sure.

Below I provide the code I am using. Initially, I generate the map the way I want except for the state names. Next, I try to overlay state abbreviations on the same map.

Unfortunately it is not working out for me. If I comment out "fill = " option from the first map, I can generate a map with state abbreviations. But that map does not show what I intend to show. I have tried several ways. I am just leaving one option in the code for the moment.

To add the state abbreviations, I am following some of the suggestions I have read in this forum. In particular, I am trying to follow the advice from a discussion titled "ggplot centered names on a map" dated February 25, 2012.

I would appreciate any help on how I can add/overlay the state abbreviations to the first map.

```
# Master US location data
states <- map_data("state")

# Read in the data
rate <- read.csv("~/R/HealthCare/Data/Test_data.csv")

names(rate) <- tolower(names(rate))
rate$numer <- as.factor(rate$numer)
rate$region <- tolower(rate$statename)


# Create data for US mapping
tomap <- merge(states, rate, sort = FALSE, by = "region")
tomap <- tomap[order(tomap$order), ]


  ## US Map

 # 1. Target Map (w/o state abbr)
p <- qplot(long, lat, data = tomap, 
            group = group, 
            fill = numer,
            geom = "polygon")

p + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greens",
                    guide = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE),
                    labels = c("1st cat", "2nd cat", 
                               "3rd cat", "4th cat")) 



  # 2. Add State Abbreviations to Target Map
stannote <- aggregate(cbind(long, lat, group, numer) ~ stateabbr, data = tomap, 
                      FUN=function(x)mean(range(x)))


q <-  qplot(long, lat, data = tomap, 
            group = group,
            #fill = numer,
            fill = "red", #testing
            geom = "polygon") +
  geom_text(data=stannote, aes(long, lat, label = stateabbr), color = "blue", size=3) +
  coord_map()

q
```

The sample data file looks like the following –

```
StateName,StateAbbr,Numer
Alabama,AL,0
Alaska,AK,0
Arizona,AZ,0
Arkansas,AR,0
California,CA,0
Colorado,CO,0
Connecticut,CT,0
Delaware,DE,0
District of Columbia,DC,1
Florida,FL,0
Georgia,GA,0
Hawaii,HI,0
Idaho,ID,1
Illinois,IL,0
Indiana,IN,0
Iowa,IA,1
Kansas,KS,0
Kentucky,KY,1
Louisiana,LA,1
Maine,ME,2
Maryland,MD,0
Massachusetts,MA,2
Michigan,MI,0
Minnesota,MN,1
Mississippi,MS,0
Missouri,MO,0
Montana,MT,0
Nebraska,NE,0
Nevada,NV,1
New Hampshire,NH,1
New Jersey,NJ,2
New Mexico,NM,1
New York,NY,3
North Carolina,NC,0
North Dakota,ND,1
Ohio,OH,0
Oklahoma,OK,0
Oregon,OR,2
Pennsylvania,PA,0
Rhode Island,RI,0
South Carolina,SC,0
South Dakota,SD,1
Tennessee,TN,0
Texas,TX,0
Utah,UT,1
Vermont,VT,2
Virginia,VA,0
Washington,WA,2
West Virginia,WV,0
Wisconsin,WI,0
Wyoming,WY,0
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Is this a problem arising from the difference between `StateAbbr` and `stateabbr` (case)?

Comment: @Hugh I converted all the variable names (including StateAbbr) to lower case right after I read in the CSV file and I use the lowercase variable names throughout.  The issue I face is that when I try to add the state abbreviations to the original chart, I get "Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale." The variable used in the original "fill=" statement is "numer", which a discrete variable (the original chart works fine with that variable). I don't quite understand the error message. That's why I was experimenting with other "fill=", as it appears in the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As often happens to me with R, it turns out the error message was telling you exactly what was happening (it just takes a while to figure it out).  Your `numer` variable in your second dataset `stannote` is continuous (check the structure with `str(stannote)` to see this). So you can just change that variable to a factor.  Watch out, though:  when you used `cbind` in aggregate I think you forced the factor to be turned into a numeric variable and so `numer` in `stannote` goes from 1-4 instead of 0-3.

Option 1:

```
stannote$numer = factor(stannote$numer, labels = c(0, 1, 2, 3))
qplot(long, lat, data = tomap, 
            group = group,
            fill = numer, #testing
            geom = "polygon") +
  geom_text(data=stannote, aes(long, lat, label = stateabbr),
                    color = "blue", size=3) + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greens")
```

Alternatively, you could remove the `fill` aesthetic that you set for the overall plot from the call to `geom_text` using `fill = NULL`.  You don't actually need fill for the text, just for the polygons.  This is a situation where if you were using `ggplot` instead of `qplot` you might just set the fill aesthetic for `geom_polygon`.

Option 2:

```
stannote$numer = as.numeric(stannote$numer)
qplot(long, lat, data = tomap, 
            group = group,
            fill = numer, #testing
            geom = "polygon") +
  geom_text(data=stannote, aes(long, lat, label = stateabbr, fill = NULL),
                    color = "blue", size=3) + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greens")
```

Comment: Thanks so much. You are absolutely right, the solution was hidden in the error message. It works great now.